# How to define a custom layer in Pytorch

Tags: deep-neural-networks, activation-functions, pytorch, hidden-layers

I am new to PyTorch and seeking your help regarding a problem I have. I need to add a costume layer to a NN in training phase. Please see the figure which shows a simple DNN with the custom layer. NN is trying to solve a regression problem.

Let's consider the simplest case, $f_1(input)=f_2(input)=f_3(input)=sin(a\times input)$, where $a$ is constant. How can I handle such an NN in PyTorch.

Also, can we treat $a$ as a trainable parameter as well if we don't assume it as a predefined constant?

I appreciate any hint or similar example using PyTorch.

[image]

Comment: This site is more heavily focussed on theory than related Stack Exchange sites. As you are asking for Python code using a specific framework, then you may have better luck in Data Science stack exchange or even original Stack Overflow (if you show some code so far without the custom layer implemented). Your diagram suggests this is not a full custom layer, but a custom activation function (either combined with or instead of the activation layer from the previous layer). It is worth clarifying that, separately of where you ask.